# Finite group $G$ has a generating set with following condition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Prove that $G$ has a generating set $\Omega$,
with $|\Omega| \leq \lfloor \log_2 \lvert G \rvert \rfloor$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a proof of that? (And what does $|G|$ mean if $G$ is infinite?)

Comment: I see this in a note without any proof or reference.

Comment: let $p$ the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ then $|\Omega|\leq log_p(|G|)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We prove that if $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ comprise a minimal generating set, then $|G|\geq 2^n$. This is true if $n=0$. Inductively we may assume that the subgroup $H$ generated by the first $n-1$ generators has order at least $2^{n-1}$ and is not the whole group. The two cosets $H$ and $g_nH$ are disjoint and have size at least $2^{n-1}$, so $G$ has size at least $2^{n-1}+ 2^{n-1}=2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that the smallest group $G$  with  a minimal set of $n$ generators has $|G|=2^n$.

Comment: Hmm, I would prove that as a corollary of the sought result ...

Comment: I believe there's an implicit assumption that we are talking about a minimal generating set.

Comment: I've edited my post appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

> **Lemma.** Assume there is an $n$-element set generating a proper subgroup of order $k$.  Then there is an $(n+1)$-element set that generates a subgroup of order at least $2k$.

Then build up from zero generators to $\log_2 |G|$ generators by induction.